# Running AngularJS tests with maven

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, maven, angularjs

Hi I am new to AngularJS and testing JS. I need to run my tests with maven. I have created a controller and a service for a small app and they are working. Now i want to write tests (yes, broke the rule to write tests while developing) for the JS code I have. I have so far managed to invoke the tests with maven.

I am using jasmine-maven-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <jsSrcDir>src/main/webapp/js</jsSrcDir>
        <jsTestSrcDir>src/test/webapp/js</jsTestSrcDir>
        <specIncludes>
            <include>*Spec.js</include>
        </specIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When run *mvn test* I see the following

[INFO] --- jasmine-maven-plugin:1.3.1.3:test (default) @ pod-manager-web-ang ---
2013-10-14 14:57:34.322:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.13.v20130916
2013-10-14 14:57:34.378:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:56475
**[INFO] Executing Jasmine Specs**

Then a failure with the message below

```
[ERROR] Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "angular" is not defined. (http://localhost:56475/src/controllers/controller.js#3)
[ERROR] at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3603)
[ERROR] at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3587)
[ERROR] at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3657)
[ERROR] at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1685)
```

*The question is where should I place the angular.js and other angular JS files for these tests to run?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use preloadSources to load Angular, jQuery and other needed libraries.

```
<configuration>
    <preloadSources>
        <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/vendor/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js</source>
        <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/vendor/angular/1.0.5/angular.js</source>
    </preloadSources>
    <jsSrcDir>src/main/webapp/js</jsSrcDir>
    <jsTestSrcDir>src/test/webapp/js</jsTestSrcDir>
    <specIncludes>
        <include>*Spec.js</include>
    </specIncludes>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi kseb, Thanks for the response, why would i need jquery files, right now my code is working fine without them. Is this something i would need for running the unit tests?

Comment: I needed jQuery because of limited jqLite implementation. I was using more things from jQuery. So for me it was important to have it included. Your need may be different though.

Comment: Using the preloadSources tag is the correct option to my original question. But i still couldn't get the tests run headless, i am able to run them using "mvn jasmine:bdd" command. I have not included jquery as i don't need them.

Comment: Look at the example on http://plnkr.co/edit/naLJ3mD3UjoTqcF9nG8O . There is my working version of pom.xml with jasmine tests integration. Tests are firing after executing in a console: `mvn clean install`. I hope it helps.

Comment: I got it working by using the PhantomJS driver, 
     <webDriverClassName>org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver</webDriverClassName>

Comment: So the thing was completely different.